# Create java chars using jruby

Tags: java, ruby, jruby, minecraft-forge

Hi i need a char using jruby but all i have is this error:

```
org.jruby.embed.InvokeFailedException: java.lang.ClassCastException: net.minecraft.item.ItemFood cannot be cast to java.lang.Character
```

i'm making a mod for minecraft using jruby, i am trying make new recipes, this is the way to make this in java:

```
GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(Items.apple), new Object[]{
        "XXX",
        "XYX",
        "XXX",
        'X', //required char
        Items.arrow,
        'Y', //required char
        Items.bone
 });
```

this is my ruby code:

```
xx = 'XY'
blockStack = ItemStack.new(newBlock)
GameRegistry.addRecipe(blockStack, ["XYX", xx[0], Items.apple, xx[1], Items.redstone].to_java)
```

how to create java chars using ruby?
i tried use .charAt() but this return a number
and .toCharArray() but dont work too.

Comment: The array that you are using to construct the recipe has only 5 items, in java it has 7 items, it might be that...

Comment: Java doesn't have special characters any more than Ruby, C, Perl or any other language. Probably what you're talking about are the Unicode character sets.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

integers might be converted to chars (`42.to_java(:char)`) thus try passing that in (unfortunately you'll need to know the char's ordinal representation, this is a bit [annoying](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/pull/2549))